# AngularJS 1.6 - ng-repeat track by - still make sense?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular 1.6 `track by` for `ng-repeat` still make sense? Is it good practice for performance?

Comment: makes sense if you have duplicates in your array

Comment: Answer is right in the documentation for `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every object in your array has a unique identifier property, you should use that property for the `track by` part. For example:

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 1, name: "some name"},
    {id: 2, name: "some name"}
];
```

Your ng-repeat would look like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id"
```

As stated in the AngularJS docs:

> Best Practice: If you are working with objects that have a unique identifier property, you should track by this identifier instead of the object instance, e.g. item in items track by item.id. Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.

However if your array looks like this, where there's the possibility of having dupes:

```
$scope.items = [
    {name: "name1"},
    {name: "name1"},
    {name: "name2"},
];
```

Your ng-repeat would look like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"
```

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeKk7/) you can check the performance impact of using or not using `track by`.

[Source of the fiddle](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/)